# assumptions of the mixed-effects Cox regression model

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

In typical Cox proportional hazards models the assumption of proportionality can be tested using the function cox.zph() in R, but I am doing a mixed effect cox model with the coxme function in R. Is there a way to asses assumptions in a mixed-effect cox model?